# LPCTSTR to LPWSTR conversion is not defined in Mingw32 in winnt.h

Tags: c, winapi, mingw, mingw32

I am using mingw32, where I cant find type definition of LPCTSTR to LPCWSTR. But the same is defined in  mingw64 as below.

`typedef LPCWSTR PCTSTR,LPCTSTR;`

But my code `works fine in mingw32` without any error even I added `LPCTSTR` in my code, and if I change the compiler options to mingw64 I am getting  lots of errors.

Winnt.h in mingw32:

```
typedef TCHAR TBYTE,*PTCH,*PTBYTE;
typedef TCHAR *LPTCH,*PTSTR,*LPTSTR,*LP,*PTCHAR;
typedef const TCHAR *LPCTSTR;
```

winnt.h in mingw64:

```
typedef LPWSTR LPTCH,PTCH;
typedef LPWSTR PTSTR,LPTSTR;
typedef LPCWSTR PCTSTR,LPCTSTR;
typedef LPUWSTR PUTSTR,LPUTSTR;
typedef LPCUWSTR PCUTSTR,LPCUTSTR;
typedef LPWSTR LP;
```

How to solve this? why I am not getting any error in mingw32, with UNICODE defined?

Comment: Why do you expect errors in mingw32? The definition of `LPCTSTR` is right there in the code you posted. And we can't help you with the errors you got with mingw64 unless we see your code and the actual errors...

Comment: @interjay my doubt here is, I can see LPCTSTR typedef'ed as LPCWSTR when UNICODE is defined in Mingw64 and the same typedef is not there in Mingw32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` is being defined in mingw32 as:

```
typedef const TCHAR *LPCTSTR;
```

When `UNICODE` is defined, `TCHAR` maps to `WCHAR`, making `LPCTSTR` equivilent to `LPCWSTR`.

When `UNICODE` is not defined, `TCHAR` maps to `CHAR` instead, making `LPCTSTR` equivilent to `LPCSTR`.